# ::first-letter also styles first character

Tags: html, css

I have this Text:

```css
p::first-letter {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>"Welcome!"</p>
```

but then i realized that also the `"` got styled.

I tried using `::before` but that didn't work either:

```css
p::first-letter {
  color: red;
}

p::before {
  content: '"';
}
```

```html
<p>Welcome!"</p>
```

How could I manage to only style the first letter (In clean code)?

Comment: I'm not certain if you can get around it strictly using the pseudo element if you're trying to avoid quotes but you could wrap the w in a ```span``` and give it a class then style that class to your needs.

Comment: I had the same idea but that wouldnt be clean code... :o

Comment: Just so you know, this is expected. See [MDN - ::first:letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)

Comment: To add to @AmauryHanser's comment, if any text is injected into the html using `:before` and `content`, and also presumably any injections from JavaScript, then `:first-letter` will be matched to that of the first letter and punctuation of the newly generated text. - source from [MDN ::first-letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply `float` the first character and use `:after` not `:before`

```css
p::first-letter {
  color: red;
}

p::after {
  content: '"';
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<p>Welcome!"</p>
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, a good point, but as for me it is a bit unusual to add a single quote at the end. But definitely it solves the issue that author had. And definitely better than changing the position of an element.

Answer (score 1):

### Here is what I came up with after trying and thinking a bit of CSS/HTML principles:

I will be using `display: inline-block;` because `::first-letter` requires a block for its content to work.

**Please pay attention that I am using `<span></span>` tag and not `<p></p>` tag as the `HTML W3 Consortium` consider it as invalid html code.
You can check your code about validity [here](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)**

Take a look at the [sandbox](https://jsfiddle.net/UtmostCreator/vt532qk0/) or at the live example here:

```css
.quote span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.quote span::first-letter {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<q class="quote" cite="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062622/quotes/qt0396921"><span>This is a great quote</span></q>
```

*More info on tags here:*

- [see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/q) what is `<q></q>` tag is and how to use it;
- [see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) more about what is `<span></span>` (e.g. text wrapper to any text you want to display and style depending on your needs);
- look through [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) to see what is the `::first-letter`, how it works, and what is needed for it to work properly.

Comment: Mhmmm, is there maybe a way to achieve this with only css?

Comment: I was also thinking about making `::after` with a position absolute and move to the left side, but then there is a problem with the end (right side of a quote). However, there is another downside here (using `position` property is not very good for performance as it is more difficult to render). So, HTML `span` tag should provide a bit better performance overall. I will think of other way on how to do this, and if anything I will get back here for letting you know it

Answer (score 0):

You can `text-indent` the paragraph and use a `before` positioned in absolute, but you have to manually set the indent that depends on text-size. It is not a super-clean solution: it is a "not so dirty" one.

```css
p {
  text-indent: 5px;
}
p::first-letter {
  position:relative;
  color: red;
}

p::before {
  position:absolute;
  content: '"';
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Welcome"</p>
```

Answer (score -3):

p::first-letter, it will always style the first character, to style W put a span element like W then style the span.

Comment: We already know that. We‘re trying to achieve a perfect result with clean code